# Nuxtjs conf error setting up github pages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to enable github pages for deployment in nuxt. Following the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/github-pages/) though I cannot get it correct in the conf file.

This is what they note to add in the file. I have added it in several locations in the file but each time it errors.

```
/* nuxt.config.js */
// only add `router.base = '/<repository-name>/'` if `DEPLOY_ENV` is `GH_PAGES`
const routerBase = process.env.DEPLOY_ENV === 'GH_PAGES' ? {
  router: {
    base: '/<repository-name>/'
  }
} : {}

export default {
  ...routerBase
}
```

My code for exports.

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'spa',
  const routerBase = process.env.DEPLOY_ENV === 'GH_PAGES' ?
      {router: {base: '/mortalcatalyst.github.io/'}} :
      {} export default {router: {base: '/mortalcatalyst.github.io/'}},
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      {charset: 'utf-8'},
      {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
      {hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description}
    ],
    link: [{rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico'}]
  }, # rest of config (standard)
```

Error

```
 FATAL  Invalid or unexpected token                                  22:06:37

  const routerBase = process.env.DEPLOY_ENV === 'GH_PAGES' ? {
  ^

  SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)


   ╭──────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                              │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                         │
   │                                              │
   │   SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token   │
   │                                              │
   ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────╯

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! github@1.0.0 generate: `nuxt generate`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the github@1.0.0 generate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a malformed JS object at the 3th line:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'spa',
  const routerBase = ...  // it must be a "key: value" not a "const" declaration
```

So you can replace by an external declaration, then add variable with spread operator `...` on `export default`:

```
const routerBase = process.env.DEPLOY_ENV === 'GH_PAGES' ?
  {router: {base: '/mortalcatalyst.github.io/'}} :
  {}

export default {
  ...routerBase,
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {

  }
}
```

Comment: I still receive same error though. It shows the same syntax error in editor as well. I changed to look like your code but it seems the same to me.

Comment: module.exports = {
  mode: 'spa',
  const routerBase = process.env.DEPLOY_ENV === 'GH_PAGES' ?
      {router: {base: '/mortalcatalyst.github.io/'}} :
      {}

      export default {
        router: {base: '/mortalcatalyst.github.io/'},
            /*...

Comment: I just don't know where exactly to put it in the file so it wont error.